# How to increase the velocity of a reaction?

Tags: kinetics, temperature

I'm doing relatively simple Chemistry but I've been given a formula for the velocity of a reaction.

$$v= k \cdot c_\mathrm A^a$$

and

$$k= A \cdot \mathrm e^{E_\mathrm a/RT}$$

As a result, from that formula, surely decreasing the temperature $T$ would increase the velocity of the reaction? As that would increase the value of $k$ and therefore drive up the reaction speed? Also, same thinking, increasing the activation energy $E_\mathrm a$.

I know that's wrong, because common sense. But the formula is lying to my face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be $-E_a/RT$

Therefor, increasing the temperature, lowering the activation energy (catalysis), or increasing the concentration of reactant(s) would increase the reaction velocity.